# Is it possible to rename application on IBM WebSphere Application Server?

Tags: websphere

[image]

It would be helpful if you're using, for instance, remote app deploying using wsadmin and don't want to change script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible to rename an application.  The only option is to uninstall and reinstall.